# JQM external panel doesn't include custom colors

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I just tried to apply nativedroid JQM theme to external panels. I know that `enhanceWithin()` should solve this completely but it doesn't. Nativedroid css colors aren't aplied to the external panel. I made a JSFiddle to demonstrate this behaviour. With normal panel everythings ok but the external panel appears without the green style that should be there.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/08rL2t1y/1/)

How to solve this problem?

[image: jqm external panel styling issue]

```html
<script id="panel-init">
  $(function() {
    $("#externalPanel").panel().enhanceWithin();
  });

</script>


<div data-role="panel" id="externalPanel" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="push" data-theme="b">
  <!-- panel content goes here -->
  <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-dividertheme="b" data-inset="false">
    <li>External Panel</li>
    <li data-icon='false'><a href="#"><i class='lIcon fa fa-coffee'></i>Need a Coffee</a></li>
    <li data-icon='false'><a href="#"><i class='lIcon fa fa-beer'></i>Have a Beer</a></li>
    <li data-icon='false'><a href="#"><i class='lIcon fa fa-music'></i>Play Music</a></li>
    <li data-icon='false'><a href="#"><i class='lIcon fa fa-fire'></i>Make a fire</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<!-- /panel -->

<div data-role="page" id="one" data-theme='b'>
  <div data-role="panel" id="internalPanel" data-position-fixed="true" data-display="push" data-theme="b">
    <!-- panel content goes here -->
    <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b" data-dividertheme="b" data-inset="false">
      <li>Internal Panel</li>
      <li data-icon='false'><a href="#"><i class='lIcon fa fa-coffee'></i>Need a Coffee</a></li>
      <li data-icon='false'><a href="#"><i class='lIcon fa fa-beer'></i>Have a Beer</a></li>
      <li data-icon='false'><a href="#"><i class='lIcon fa fa-music'></i>Play Music</a></li>
      <li data-icon='false'><a href="#"><i class='lIcon fa fa-fire'></i>Make a fire</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /panel -->
  <div data-role="header" data-theme='b'>
    <h1>Single page</h1>
  </div>
  <!-- /header -->

  <div role="main" class="ui-content">
    <a href="#externalPanel" data-theme="b" data-role="button">Open EXTERNAL panel</a>
    <a href="#internalPanel" data-theme="b" data-role="button">Open INTERNAL panel</a>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea
      takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores
      et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  </div>
  <!-- /content -->

</div>
<!-- /page -->
```

Comment: just add class `ui-page-theme-b` to `body` as panel inherits from page.

Comment: @Omar You're right! Could you please post it as an answer because you actually solved it for me. And thanks a lot! ;)

Comment: Glad it helped :) post an answer with some explanation ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case somebody has a similar problem - the solution is:

Add the class `ui-page-theme-b` to the body tag because the panel inherits from the page.

Omar told me this in his comment and advised to post it by myself as answer.